# Expected unqualified - ID _config

Tags: c++, c

So I'm brand new to c++ and just started the beginner class. The professor has given us the exact prompt to put into the program and I am still receiving an error. I have checked over and over for any small flaws such as spacing or random ";" that a lot of people seem to do, but still no results. Can anyone see anything wrong with what I have down?

[image: screenshot of XCode & main.cpp]
[image: screenshot of __config]

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Build time error, "Expected unqualified - id

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual code and error messages as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Remove asterisk (*) right below "//Purpose of  this program ..." and try it again.

Comment: It fixed the issue, but I have a question. My professor told us to put that asterisk there, but he is using Microsoft visual c++. Are there different ways to put in coding on different programs? I'm sorry if I sound ignorant, I am very new to this, but I want to learn.

Comment: It is not a difference between xCode and Microsoft Visual C++.
It seems like you mixed multi-line comments and single-line comments. You must pick only one to use. See following.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_comments.htm